# How to exclude the password from being updated in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I exclude the password from being updated. Here is my update controller for user.

```
  def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

my edit page contains the first name without password but the password is still getting stored with null value. I tried to use :on => create but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect attributes getting mass assigned in a whitelist approach with `attr_accessible` or in a blacklist approach with `attr_protected` in the model:

```
attr_protected :password
```